# Why Ansible variable override strategy doesn't seem to behave as documented?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

Suppose I have a parameter (ansible variable) which I want to keep the same for several inventories except for one.

By using the playbook level group_vars and inventory level group_vars, according to [the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#how-variables-are-merged), I could define a group for all inventories and still be able to override variables in the inventory by targeting the children because the children have precedence over the parents.

### Example

**inventories/testervm/hosts**

```
[central:children]
testervm

[testervm]
127.0.0.1 ansible_connection=local
```

**group_vars/central.yaml**

```
parameter: "I want to be overridden"
```

**inventories/testervm/group_vars/central.yaml**

```
parameter: "This override shouldn't work."
```

**inventories/testervm/group_vars/testervm.yaml**

```
parameter: "This override should work"
```

**playbook.yaml**

```
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - the_role
```

**roles/the_role/tasks/main.yaml**

```
- name: printing the parameter
  debug:
    msg: "{{ parameter }}"
```

When I run

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.9.7
[...]

$ ansible-playbook -i inventories/testervm playbook.yaml 

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [the_role : printing the parameter] ***************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "I want to be overridden"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Needless to say I would have expected to see `"msg": "This override should work"`.

What am I getting wrong ?

[EDIT] fixed wrong paths in file paths

[EDIT]
PS: Thanks to Vladimir I ended up doing this trick, maybe somebody can find it useful. In the playbook I added this task:

```yaml
    - name: include variable overrides
      include_vars:
        file: "{{ item }}"
      when: item is file
      with_items: "{{ [inventory_dir ~ '/group_vars/_overrides/'] | product(groups.keys()) | map('join') | product(['.yaml']) | map('join') | list }}"
      tags: always
```

Example: inventories/testervm/group_vars/_overrides/testervm.yaml

This makes possible to have this precedence order in the group vars:

- inventory group_vars/_overrides (highest)
- playbook group_vars
- inventory group_vars (lowest)

Comment: Actually by moving inventory/testervm/group_vars/testervm.yaml into group_vars/testervm.yaml I obtain the desired effect but still I find the question valid because it's like  inventory/testervm/group_vars/testervm.yaml is completely ignored whereas I think it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. *playbook group_vars/** (7.) is a higher precedence than *inventory group_vars/** (6.). See [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence).

---

The result of the test is correct

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yaml 
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - the_role
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/the_role/tasks/main.yaml 
- name: printing the parameter
  debug:
    msg: "{{ parameter }}"
```

```yaml
shell> cat inventories/testervm/hosts 
[central:children]
testervm

[testervm]
127.0.0.1 ansible_connection=local
```

```yaml
shell> cat inventories/testervm/group_vars/central.yaml
parameter: "Inventory group_vars/central.yaml"
```

```yaml
shell> cat inventories/testervm/group_vars/testervm.yaml
parameter: "Inventory group_vars/testervm.yaml"
```

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/central.yaml
parameter: "Playbook group_vars/central.yaml"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i inventories/testervm playbook.yaml

    "msg": "Playbook group_vars/central.yaml"
```

---

Q: "*Override a variable only in one specific inventory ... 12 [options](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence) (above 10.) how to override host_vars and group_vars none of which applies to groups.*"

A: All of the 12 options apply, of course. This is the consequence of higher precedence. For example, the playbook below shows how to override *parameter* by *include_vars* (precedence 18.) if the host is a member of the group *testervm*

```yaml
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - the_role
  tasks:
    - include_vars: files/testervm.yaml
      when: inventory_hostname in groups.testervm
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ parameter }}"
```

```yaml
shell> cat files/testervm.yaml
parameter: "Include_vars files/testervm.yaml"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i inventories/testervm playbook.yaml

    "msg": "Playbook group_vars/central.yaml"
    "msg": "Include_vars files/testervm.yaml"
```

Comment: I understand variable precedence, but I assumed that it applies for variables defined for the same group and not for variables defined for different groups.

Comment: how would you advice to solve the problem of wanting to override a variable only in one specific inventory while avoiding to repeat the variable for all other (many) inventories?

Comment: This would depend on the details of the use-case. There are many options on how to define group_vars and host_vars. In addition to this, in the [precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence) you can see 12 options (above 10.) how to override host_vars and group_vars. See [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and open unambiguous question.

Comment: `In addition to this, in the precedence you can see 12 options (above 10.) how to override host_vars and group_vars` none of which applies to groups. My issue is simple and not ambiguous: how can I avoid repeating some group variables in all inventories but still have the ability to override a few in a specific inventory? Imagine following: I want a parameter in group X to be in general a value, for inventory A another value and for inventory B yet another value. How to achieve this? There is basically no solution to this using group_vars without repeating the definition in all inventories.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong again. I've added an example of how to use *include_vars* (precedence 18.) to override "specific inventory" *group_vars*. Still the same, open new question. [Stop abusing the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132919/how-to-deal-with-comment-abuse).